# How to display data into <table> tag using datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, code-behind

Hello I am doing web project in VS express for web and I am quite new to c# programming and simply adjusting the syntax and format of it. I was just wandering how do you display the data in a datatable and display it in the table web page when Button1_Click is triggered:

When I click this button it will get the data:

```
<button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_Click" id="searchinfo" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>
```

And display it in this table that I made:
    
     
        
        
    
I am using code behind (aspx.cs) for the controls of my web page and this is what I made so far:

```
using MSSQLConnector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1.eyeofheaven
{
    public partial class SearchCustomer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataSet selectedAngels = connector.ExecuteQuery("select * from customer where idcustomer = 453433");
            DataTable dt = selectedAngels.Tables[0];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok sir, hmm could you provide a sample code of how to display data in your table tag? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Looks like your doing webforms. You don't need to hard code HTML. As AVD mentioned, you use controls that generate buttons, tables, etc. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [data controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx) especially [GridView](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/sorting-paging-and-filtering-data).

Add following markup in .aspx page

```
<asp:GridView runat="Server" id="data"/>
```

Code in click handler.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
   connector.ConnectionString = "SERVER=xbetasql,52292;UID=username;Password=secret;DATABASE=ATDBSQL;";

   DataSet selectedAngels = connector.ExecuteQuery("select * from customer where idcustomer = 453433");
   DataTable dt = selectedAngels.Tables[0];
   data.DataSource = dt;
   data.DataBind();
   }
```